# Connect to internet at start up wifi

Tags: android

I want update my designing app when user turn on WiFi or I want notificate user there is an update when start up or turn on WiFi device .Please Guide me what to do.

Comment: Doesn't Android already notify users of updates for installed apps?

Comment: I want show recently news when user turn on WiFi but no update my app version.

Comment: answered below to help you out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a BroadcastReceiver that is listening for the intent-filter of WIFI_STATE_CHANGED:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if(isWifiConnected(context)){
            //Do something now that wifi is connected!
        }
    }

public static boolean isWifiConnected(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(info != null){
        if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is a simple receiver that just detects a change in network state and checks if the wifi is connected.

You also need to register the receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file like so:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.yourcompany.package.NetworkChangeReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Replacing of course the correct packing location within the name field

**Note:** The Android OS does notify apps when the state has change for the wifi.. so if you need this to do a network operation it will as soon as the wifi connection is accessible (or data), but in the case of specifically needing to know when the WIFI is connected, this receiver can help you do that.

Comment: Solved thanks Lucas:)

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you so others benefit from my answer :)